# Can I track multiple Google Analytics events at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am using Event Tracking on our conversion form to pass the values of a few drop-downs to Google Analytics as events. Our conversion form is an inquiry form for our online degree programs. I only want to pass the values of the fields on form submit, so I have added the following code to the code that runs on successful submission of the form:

```
 $("#App,#InquiryForm").validate({    
   submitHandler: function (form) {
 $(".button").attr("value", "Please wait...");
 $(".button").attr("disabled", "disabled");

 _gaq.push(
     ['_trackEvent', 'Inq Form Academic Level', 'Academic Level', $('#AcademicLevel').val()],
     ['_trackEvent', 'Inq Form Delivery Time', 'Delivery Time', $('#CourseDeliveryTime').val()],
     ['_trackEvent', 'Inq Form Program Type', 'Program Type', $('#ProgramType').val()],
     ['_trackEvent', 'Inq Form Program', 'Program', $('#ProgramofInterest').val()]
);

 form.submit();
},
```

The purpose of this is to be able to segment our traffic that converted by what they were interested in. (e.g. What was the browsing behavior of visitors who inquired about our undergraduate degrees vs those that inquired about our graduate degrees).

Unfortunately, only the first event tracking script is running successfully, not the last three (regardless of what order I place them in - the first one is always the only one that is successful).

If you can help me to get this working, that would be fantastic! If not, perhaps some alternate suggestions to get at the data I need?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the `_gaq.push` for your events? Is it in an `onSubmit` or jquery function???

Comment: I updated my original question with more of the surrounding code. I didn't write the initial code, and my knowledge of jQuery is beginner-level. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested pushing multiple events with one push and it worked fine. It may be submitting the form before all the `_trackEvents` are pushed.

Try adding a `setTimeout` to the `form.submit()` to give the `_gaq.push` time to send all of them.

```
setTimeout(function(){ form.submit(); }, 200);
```

Install Chrome and the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). Look in the console (control, shift, j) for the event tracking processing.

[image]

If you don't see all of your events tracking there, then something is up maybe with the form values.

Comment: It looks like that timeout may have worked. So hard to tell when you sometimes have to wait up to 20 minutes to see the result in GA. I'll do some more testing, but thanks JK, I appreciate it!